# Image Url Testing Through Jmeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter

Please let me know how to resolve this issue i.e.

I want to test image urls(10,000 plus) through Jmeter, but jmeter showing 404 error also incase of correct image.

an example :

https://g-cdn.alwka.com/media/catalog/product/cache/e4d64343b1bc593f1c5348fe05efa4a6/3/7/3705s-1pzfu-f.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest [JMeter 5.1.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-1-released-td5728320.html)

[image]

In case of any inconsistencies between JMeter and the real browser behaviour make sure that the request you're sending with JMeter looks exactly the same as from the real browser including:

1. [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) which can be added via [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
2. [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) which can be added via [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/)

You can also use [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to get more information regarding image loading process, for example you may "see" the image returned from cache and the image doesn't exist on the server any more